# Move mysql tables to another disk/partition

Tags: partitioning, mysql

I have mysql data mounted to

```
/var/lib/mysql
```

And what I want is to move it to

```
/fast/mysql
```

My plan is following:

1. Stop mysql.
2. Rsync from `/var/lib/mysql` to `/fast/mysql`.
3. Change `my.cnf` to point to `/fast/mysql`.
4. Run mysql.

Are there any problems with my plan?

Comment: you could move the data and do a symbolic link from the original location.

Comment: @WolfgangFahl, yup, symbolic link seems fast solution. As I understood you suggest to make link from /var/lib/mysql folder to /fast/mysql folder. I mean particularly folder links, not file links?

Comment: mv /var/lib/mysql /fast/mysql;ln -s /fast/mysql /var/lib/mysql - see answer below

Answer (score 0):

If you're running apparmor, you'll need to tell it that MySQL is allowed to access the files at the new location.

Your distribution may be configured differently, but on Ubuntu 12.10, you'll need to edit this file:

`/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`

Answer (score 0):

you might want to use a symbolic link

```
mv /var/lib/mysql /fast/mysql
ln -s /fast/mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: The only question, why I just can't use point 3 from my plan? I mean why changing value in my.cnf is not good solution and I need to use link?

Comment: My answer is about the move part more than the cnf part. You proposal was copying, I don't know whether you where intending to copy.